# How to implement a Crysis ransomware master key?

Tags: decryption, ransomware, key

I see there have been master keys released to decrypt computers affected by the Crysis ransomware. If a computer is infected with Crysis, how would one actually test/run the key on the computer?

This is what one of the keys looks like on the pastebin:

```
0xa3,0xa1,0x68,0x06,0x45,0x46,0x30,0x3e,\
    0x46,0xad,0x3b,0xa7,0x59,0xac,0x4b,0x5a,\
    0x5a,0xe8,0xaa,0x5f,0xf9,0x4a,0xcd,0xf4,\
    0x64,0xaa,0x20,0x7f,0x5d,0x42,0xfc,0x39,\
    0xe5,0xbf,0x89,0xa2,0x06,0x85,0x2f,0x17,\
    0xdd,0xe2,0x5d,0x92,0x8d,0x3f,0xc9,0x05,\
    0x7c,0x08,0x0e,0xfe,0x94,0xde,0xbb,0x1a,\
    0x2d,0x0c,0x79,0x5f,0xef,0xd2,0x81,0x5e,\
    0xe6,0x2b,0xe5,0x48,0x86,0x77,0x78,0x5f,\
    0xa8,0x28,0xd2,0xc3,0xb9,0x83,0x84,0x3c,\
    0xaf,0x85,0x38,0x54,0xbd,0x0c,0x76,0x10,\
    0x1c,0xe6,0x3f,0x23,0xc0,0xea,0xf2,0xfb,\
    0x2b,0x0a,0x56,0x6e,0x76,0xe7,0x94,0x82,\
    0xf8,0xd8,0x87,0x21,0xfe,0x50,0xde,0x6f,\
    0x09,0x2e,0xb1,0x55,0xc5,0xce,0x2e,0x10,\
    0xcd,0x81,0xe1,0x11,0x86,0x90,0xf5,0x99,\
```